# IE8 !important bug?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I might be missing something else, but im working on a site i didnt buid which has loads of very messy css and multiple !important overrides. One layout issue is fine in all browsers except some versions of IE.

When I look at the css with developer tools i can see the margin of 1em is being overiden by a margin of 0.5em, however the margin it too big on the page. Even though the margin of 1em looks like its being overridden (in developer tools) when I disable the style it works fine, in other words the margin becomes less.

So, are their any bugs where IE doesn't respect the normal hierarchy of overrides if multiple !importants are used? Or could this be a bug in the developer tools instead?

By overrides I mean something like the example below, where the 2nd css should override the first:

```
.div2 {
    margin: 1em !important;
}

body .div2 {
    margin: 0.5em !important;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "some versions of IE" **What** versions?

Comment: Your example does not fail in IE6, the worst browser in history. If you are testing this in Internet Explorer versions below 6, I fear you cannot be helped.

If you link to a jsfiddle like so http://jsfiddle.net/eSnue/ with the whole code (or the site you're working on itself), it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Its only happening in IE8, not 6,7 or 9. I cant upload the site as its generated locally from java files.

Comment: @Jonas G. Drange: IE6 doesn't even come close, that title would be given to Netscape 4.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in IE8 form the fiddle I pasted above. If you isolate the code above, is the error present still in IE8?

@BoltClock fortunately for us then that Netscape 4 does not have the same, significant market share as Internet Explorer 6 (9,7%).

Comment: got a similar problem: an `!important` set to override later code is ignored on IE8

Answer (score 0):

inline style override external style

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, but just checked and no inline styles.